# Responsive square depending on content width

Tags: css

*#wrapper* should be a square with the width of the *#text*. Longer text should result in a larger square. Line breaks aren't necessary. How does this work in CSS? The HTML can be modified if needed.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXOjJB

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">Lorem ipsum!</div>
</div>
```

This is how it should look like:

[image: Goal]

Comment: This question might be downvoted as 'low research effort'. You should just use display: inline-block properties for your divs, check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ze79mvh5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.wrapper-outer {
  display: inline-block; /* make as wide as text */
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper-outer:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.wrapper-outer:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  height: 0; /* collapse the element */
  padding: 50% 20px; /* top and bottom padding equal to half the width of parent; this gives us a height equal to the width of the parent */
}

.text {
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* move text up to center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-outer">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum!</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-outer">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="text">A</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-outer">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum! Lorem ipsum!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set padding in the child of wrapper

```
#text {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    padding-top: 35%;
}
```

check: https://jsfiddle.net/dLs9sj5y/

Comment: With line-height:0; padding-top:50%; this really works!